# Shrink disk image

Tags: dd, ext4, luks, ntfs, disk-image

I have several disk images stored at my fileserver at the moment, these are mainly system images created with dd. The reason for why I have created these images is because I needed the harddrive for something else, so I have created a image that I can later restore at the harddrive when it's available.

The problem is that the disk images are pretty size consuming, and there is a lot of free space inside of the images, so is it possible to shrink the images to only contain the actual content of the disk? Let me show you a example, I did mount one of the images to get an example.

```
Disk.img (500GB)
Disk.imgp1 (Total:1GB/Free:920MB) ext2 /boot
Disk.imgp2 (Total:4GB/Free:4GB) swap swap
Disk.imgp3 (Total:495GB/Free:390GB) ext4 /
```

As you guys can see, there is lot of free space but still the images takes up 500GB. Is there away to shrink it ~106GB, and then grow it back before restoring it on the harddrive again? Mainly I have images with GPT and DOS tables with EXT and NTFS partitions (Some of the partitions are encrypted with LUKS).

Comment: You could use Clonezilla to create backups only for allocated data, or use the Encase image format: http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Encase_image_file_format

Answer (score 4):

[This tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20200602173912/https://softwarebakery.com/shrinking-images-on-linux) appears to be what you're looking for. Essentially, you mount the disk image, use GParted to trim it down to size, and then use fdisk to truncate it.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the essential steps discussed in the link. :)